Dynamic Python visuals in PowerBI
I am trying to create a Python visual in PowerBI that changes based on an input query by the user.
I have a function that reads the user's input and return a corresponding response in the form of an image which shows up on the visual window.
Right now, the user query is hard-coded. Is there a way to make it dynamic, by having it be able to pick up a user input and provide the resulting output?
I tried creating a widget outside of PowerBI that allows the user to input something, and then stores it on the device. The Python code then picks up the stored value to produce the output. This worked, but it was a separate app, and I want to be able to do this entirely on PowerBI.
